# ArrayList of class, get specific value created in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

May be the Title isn't a specific one, I just don't know how to call it. I will explain you in detail

I have these classes:

```
public class ChannelComponent {

    private String name;
    private String mode; //(1P1C / XPXC / 1PXC)
    private List<SourceProvidedPort> publishers = new ArrayList<SourceProvidedPort>();
    private List<SinkRequiredPort> subscribers = new ArrayList<SinkRequiredPort>();

    public ChannelComponent(String name, String mode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public boolean canISubscribe(SinkRequiredPort newPort) {
        if ((mode.equals("1P1C") || mode.equals("1PXC")) && subscribers.size() < 1) {
            subscribers.add(newPort);
            return true;
        } else if (mode.equals("XPXC")) {
            subscribers.add(newPort);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getMode() {
        return mode;
    }

    public void printChannel() {
        System.out.println("[" + name + "," + mode + "]" + "\n");
    }

}
```

**TestCentralRegistry**

```
public class TestCentralRegistry {

    private List<ChannelComponent> channels = new ArrayList<ChannelComponent>();

    public void addChannelComponent(ChannelComponent c) {
        channels.add(c);
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
        TestCentralRegistry demo = new TestCentralRegistry();

        demo.addChannelComponent(new ChannelComponent("channel1", "1P1C"));
        demo.addChannelComponent(new ChannelComponent("channel2", "XPXC"));

    }
}
```

In the **TestCentralRegistry** class I created 2 channelComponents, these channels I would like to compare their **mode** value in the method **canISubscribe** (located in the **ChannelComponent** class). But how come, I could retrieve the values created in the **TestCentralRegistry** to read them in the **ChannelComponent** class?

what am I missing?

Because, from another class **TestChannel** I'm going to have a **ChannelComponent** reference, invoke the method *canISubscribe*

```
public class TestChannel {
    ChannelComponent channelComponent;

    public void callSubscribe(SinkRequiredPort newPort){
        channelComponent.canISubscribe(newPort);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TestChannel testChannel = new TestChannel();
        SinkRequiredPort sinkPort = new SinkRequiredPort();
        sinkPort.setWantsUse("channel1");

        testChannel.callSubscribe(sinkPort);

    }   
}
```

And I need to compare the values, created in the *TestCentralRegistry* and *TestChannel* to see if there is a matching. I know that I still need to add some lines like getting the value from the **newPort.getWantsUse();** and compare it with the channelComponent *name* ... but still I need the value created in the *TestCentralRegistry*

I hope my question is clear
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Hint: A) dont even start building if (mode.equals("A") OR "B" or "C") - that is a road to desaster B) a method named **canISubscribe** should **never ever** manipulate the **state** of the underlying object: the name of a method tells what it does. "canISubscribe" doesnt tell you what will happen inside the method.

Comment: @GhostCat could you please write a small example, to see how i can improve it , please

Comment: I already told: you start by using method names that tell you what is going on. So, in your case, you could have "canISubscribe" and "addSubscription" .

Comment: You see, anything else would be really too time consuming. Your code gives enough "content" for review and improve for **hours** of time. Long story short: A) read books like "Clean code" by Robert Martin B) find real people that are more experienced than you and have them review your code.

Comment: Alright @GhostCat I will do that, thank you for your advices!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try holding a reference to TestCentralRegistry in ChannelComponent.

```
public class ChannelComponent {

    private String name;
    private String mode; //(1P1C / XPXC / 1PXC)
    private List<SourceProvidedPort> publishers = new ArrayList<SourceProvidedPort>();
    private List<SinkRequiredPort> subscribers = new ArrayList<SinkRequiredPort>();
    private TestCentralRegistry testCentralRegistry;

    public ChannelComponent(String name, String mode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.mode = mode;
    }

    public void registerTestCentralRegistry( TestCentralRegistry testCentralRegistry) {
        this.testCentralRegistry = testCentralRegistry;
    }
}
```

Register your TestCentralRegistry as shown below:

```
public class TestCentralRegistry {

    private List<ChannelComponent> channels = new ArrayList<ChannelComponent>();

    public void addChannelComponent(ChannelComponent c) {
        channels.add(c);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        TestCentralRegistry demo = new TestCentralRegistry();

        ChannelComponent cc1 = new ChannelComponent("channel1", "1P1C");
        cc1.registerTestCentralRegistry( demo);
        ChannelComponent cc2 = new ChannelComponent("channel2", "XPXC");
        cc2.registerTestCentralRegistry( demo);

        demo.addChannelComponent( cc1);
        demo.addChannelComponent( cc2);
    }
}
```

Then, you can retrieve the values created in the TestCentralRegistry by calling `testCentralRegistry.getX()` from ChannelComponent.